# CS Script not working

Tags: c#-4.0

I have setup a dynamic script (using CSScriptLibrary) in my C# program as follows:

```
string sqlReturnValue= cmd.ExecuteQuery();;
dynamic script = CSScript.Evaluator
                         .LoadCode(@"using System;
                                     public class Script
                                     {
                                        string GetValue()
                                            {
                                                return " + sqlReturnValue + @";
                                            }
                                    }");
                    output = script.GetValue();
```

sqlReturnValue is a string that I get back from a SQL query similar to this:

```
"Salaried Grade 1".Substring(0, 7) == "Salaried") ? "CLA_SH_S" : "CLA_SH_H";
```

When I try to execute this the dynamic code gives me errors of `"Unexpected symbol )', expecting ;'"` & `"Unexpected symbol :', expecting ;'"`

How can I write this dynamic script such that it evaluates the ternary correctly?

Answer (score 1):

IN case someone finds this useful, I was able to get this working as follows:

```
string sqlReturnValue = cmd.ExecuteQuery();

// Use CSScript to evaluate the test string returned from the SQL Query
var Product = CSScript.Evaluator
                      .CreateDelegate(@"string Product()
                                        {
                                             return " + sqlReturnValue + @";
                                        }");

output = (string)Product();
```